# jQuery mobile appends "loading heading" to page

Tags: jquery-mobile

It seems like jQuery mobile is appending a loading message at the start up page. I really don't know what's going on but consider the following simple snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>sadFace</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <h1>;__;</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

I even have to scroll down to see the loading message. So I thought it might happen cause I'm not following the typical jQuery mobile page anatomy but:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>Page Title</title> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>;_;</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <p>Same shit, different page.</p>       
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4><a href="http://www.google.com/pacman/">need cookies :C</a></h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

the same. I'm totally stunned by this behaviour. I also test jQuery1.0rc2 with the same result even though I started my project from last week and it looks fine. What the hell is going on <.<

Looking up in [jQuery Mobile' js](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.js) I think this `initializePage: function()` is responsible for the message. I could comment out

```
//cue page loading message
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
```

or set `autoInitializePage: false` but I rather prefer a solution which is not involving a modified jQuery file (unless it's a bug).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You have to add the CSS too, then it will be fine:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
```

**In detail:**

It always puts the following HTML at the bottom of your body:

```
<div class='ui-loader ui-body-a ui-corner-all'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-loading spin'></span><h1></h1></div>
```

This is the relevant CSS (so maybe you can play with it yourself if you want)

```
.ui-loading .ui-loader { display: block; }
.ui-loader { display: none; position: absolute; opacity: .85; z-index: 100; left: 50%; width: 200px; margin-left: -130px; margin-top: -35px; padding: 10px 30px; }
```

The function `showPageLoadingMsg` adds the CSS class '.ui loading' to the HTML tag and then it becomes visible

Comment: Except the CSS does the same annoying thing that all of these frameworks do - and tries to overwrite your layout preferences for basic elements like <a>...

Comment: how do i stop it from putting an h1?

Comment: adding the jquery mobile CSS totally brakes the current website CSS, so that sucks

Comment: I encountered the same issue too, when adding the CSS link provided above. 
but using the snippet available from googleAPIs works for me:

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>

Comment: If it conflicts with other third parties CSS or your own CSS, you can simply 'overwrite' it by adding the following to your own CSS: .ui-loading .ui-loader, .ui-loader { 
 display: none ; 
}

Answer (score 19):

You can stop the autoInitializePage by using the below BEFORE you load the jquery-mobile library

```
jQuery(document).on("mobileinit", function() {
    jQuery.mobile.autoInitializePage = false;
});
```

More info here: http://api.jquerymobile.com/global-config/

Answer (score 3):

Add this to the top of your JS file

```
$.mobile.autoInitializePage = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem the word 'loading' was constant at the end (bottom) of the site and it sucks/bad.
I solved it like this: in google chrome, in inspect hover word 'loading', copy element. I created a style and as an attribute: display:none!important;
It's:

```
body > div.ui-loader.ui-corner-all.ui-body-a.ui-loader-default {
    display: none !important;
}
```